A movie about a man coming to a town to die
This is the plot I remember: A man comes to a strange town, everyone is very suspicious so he announces he came to the town to die... he doesn't really want to, but the people start treating him nice and expect him to really do it eventually and commit suicide.
The movie is probably American.
I really remember that the main character was very mysterious, and he made up the death story in a pub he entered in the town because the people there were not use to strangers and were very suspicious about the reason of his arrival to town
In the end, the town people kinda force his hand - and he kills himself...
One of the last scenes is of a woman crying - she is the only one who understands the tragedy.   
Can you please help me recognize the movie?

It sounds a little like "Leaving Las Vegas", could that be it?

@zoagli If you would like to answer the question, please do so. Be sure to explain why you think that is the correct answer.

Hi Vadip. Do you remember anything else? Country\language? Year\decade of release? Specific scenes? Genre (Was it funny? Dramatic? Suspenseful?) What the characters looked like or who played them? [@zoagli I'm pretty sure the protagonist there wanted to die the entire movie, though]

Definitely not Leaving Las Vegas.

i am pretty sure it is an american movie, it was kind a dramatic/black comedy maybe...

From your description it seems that you are looking for the 1997's movie Julian PO, starring Christian Slater and Robin Tunney (the Mentalist) .
Here's an excerpt of the plot taken from Wikipedia:

The film is the story of a depressed man who comes into a town with no future. The title character (Slater) wanders into a small sleepy town with the intent to kill himself. When the townspeople learn of his plan, Julian becomes a minor celebrity, and is offered all sorts of free perks since this is the most exciting thing to ever happen in that town. However, Julian gets attached to the town and decides life is worth living after all, much to the annoyance of the townspeople who decide to set into motion plans for his suicide, assisted or forced if need be, as long as he keeps his word and carries through with his original plans, much to his desperation and anger.

Here's the film trailer 



and here's the movie poster

